# How to communicate with a PHP server from an Android

Tags: java, php, android, android-2.2-froyo

I am looking for the easiest to way to make an Android App communicate with a PHP file. I'd prefer not to use any socket in the server. Is there a way to send POST or GET messages to the PHP using Android SDK.

Edit: I would also like to know other alternatives to HTTP requests(including the ones using Sockets).

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make in HTTP request with android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505930/make-in-http-request-with-android)

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505930/make-in-http-request-with-android

Comment: with androids HttpClient: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html

Comment: Thanks Quentin, Pico and Lawrence Cherone. :)

I've edited the question to learn about other options too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use both DefaultHttpClient from apache-httpclient or HttpURLConnection:
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html

My preference is the DefaultHttpClient from apache, for example: 
http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/httpagent.html